# How can i get property names from an Expression tree?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

My method is

```
    public Task<Product> GetProduct(int productId, params Expression<Func<Product, object>>[] properties)
    {

      var member = properties[0].Body as MemberExpression;
      var v = member.Member.Name;

    }
```

i can get a single property name by using the appropriate index

```
 var member = properties[0].Body as MemberExpression;
 var v = member.Member.Name;
```

But this is not what i want.
I would love to get all property names and string.join them with linq.

How can i do that?

Comment: What's the issue? If you know how to get (select) a single property name, you should be able to get all quite easily using simple `Select` - a pretty basic LINQ operator.

Answer (score 2):

Use `as` operator and then filter the ones which were not properties. If you use casting, it will throw exception but `as` will just return null.

```
var all =     
string.Join(", ", properties
.Select(x =>
    x.Body as MemberExpression))
.Where(x => x != null)
.Select(x =>
    x.Member.Name));
```

Comment: Thank you it seems to be close enough but it only returns the first param name

Comment: That's probably because you are passing one expression to the method. You have to pass as many expressions as you need.